# Can choose the following basis to solve hydrogen molecule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, many-body

I am trying to solve the problem of two proton and two electron problem, treating electrons quantum mechanically and ignoring the electron electron repulsion. The electronic Hamiltonian is as follows,

$$H_{e}=\frac{-1}{2}\nabla_{\vec{r_{1}}}^{2}-\frac{-1}{2}\nabla_{\vec{r_{2}}}^{2}-\frac{1}{|\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}}|}-\frac{1}{|\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{2}}|}-\frac{1}{|\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{1}}|}-\frac{1}{|\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}}|}$$

I have seen this as a two hydrogen atoms with some interactions. Hence I can construct the basis vectors as a direct product of two sets of hydrogen atom basis vectors.
{$\phi_{1s}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}}),\phi_{2s}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}}),\phi_{2p_{z}}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$} & 
{$\phi_{1s}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}}),\phi_{2s}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}}),\phi_{2p_{z}}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$} instead of taking the infinite basis set I have taken 3 basis vectors from each hydrogen atoms.
$$\phi_{1s}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}})\phi_{1s}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$$

$$\phi_{1s}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}})\phi_{2s}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$$

$$\phi_{1s}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}})\phi_{2p_{z}}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$$

$$\phi_{2s}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}})\phi_{1s}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$$

$$\phi_{2s}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}})\phi_{2s}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$$

$$\phi_{2s}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}})\phi_{2p_{z}}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$$

$$\phi_{2p_{z}}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}})\phi_{1s}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$$

$$\phi_{2p_{z}}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}})\phi_{2s}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$$

$$\phi_{2p_{z}}(\vec{r_{1}}-\vec{R_{1}})\phi_{2p_{z}}(\vec{r_{2}}-\vec{R_{2}})$$

and constructed the many body states. Anstisymmetrizing these products and got the slater determinant basis $\chi_{1}(\vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}}),\chi_{2}(\vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}}),\chi_{3}(\vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}}),\chi_{4}(\vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}})......\chi_{9}(\vec{r_{1}},\vec{r_{2}})$

Can I use this as (minimal) basis to construct the matrix elements of the Hamilton to get the eigen values and eigen vectors ? Is it a good choice to do this ?

Comment: What is your goal? If you want a decent result you have to include electron repulsion.

Comment: I don't want spin repulsion term as I assume it to be spinless particle. without this , is it a good choice of basis...I want to construct a antisymmetric orthonormal many body basis state.However, my $\chi$s are not orthogonal. Can u please tell me whether this is a good basis

Comment: Any basis is good, if there are no criteria for accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for your response..But I am still not sure whether this is right to begin with